# Como retornar valor vazio?

Tags: sql-server

Ao somar um número positivo qualquer com o resultado de uma `Subquery` obtenho como retorno `null` e preciso que retorno 0 para que seja possível somar com o primeiro valor obtido.

O que posso fazer para que a consulta me retorne um valor inteiro?

Segue Query:

```
DECLARE @TOTAL VARCHAR(100)

SET @TOTAL = (SELECT TOP 1 PTB.PATSLDCTAVALCONTAB 
                FROM PAT_SALDO_CONTA PTB  WITH (NOLOCK), CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CS WITH (NOLOCK)
               WHERE CS.PlanoCtaCodRed = PTB.PlanoCtaCodRed
                 AND PTB.PlanoCtaCodRed  = '18872'
                 AND PTB.PatSldCtaAnoMes = '201809' 
                 AND PTB.EmpCod like '%' + (CASE WHEN '01.13' = '01' THEN '01.' ELSE '01.13' END)+ '%')
            +(SELECT @TOTAL 
                     + COALESCE((SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValDeb,0))) 
                                       -(SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValCred,0))) 
                                   FROM CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CSA 
                                  WHERE CSA.PlanoCtaCodRed = '18872' 
                                    AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes >= '2018' + '' + '10'
                                    AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes <= '2018' + '' + '10'
                                    AND CSA.EmpCod like '%' + (CASE WHEN '01.13' = '01' THEN '01.' ELSE '01.13' END) + '%')
                                ,0))

SELECT @TOTAL
```

Comment: Vi que você usa o `ISNULL()` dentro do select... Não poderia usar ele novamente? por exemplo `TOTAL + ISNULL((SELECT....), 0)`

Comment: sim mas ele retorna o 0, eu queria que retornasse 10, tipo 10 + 0 = 10

Comment: Felipe, sugiro que primeiro você separe a soma para verificar os valores retornados no `total` e no `subselect`. Após a constatação de que o problema é exclusivo do retorno do `subselect` tente colocar fazer como o Matheus sugeriu. É possível que o total seja diferente de 10 como citado no comentário acima e por isso o retorno seja 0?

Answer (score 1):

Como sua query pode retornar um valor `null`, trate o retorno dela com o `ISNULL` ou `COALESCE` setando um valor 0, que deve resolver seu problema.

> COALESCE(valor, default)

O `ISNULL` e o `COALESCE` retornam o `default` caso o `valor` seja `NULL`...
Então no seu caso, por exemplo:

```
TOTAL = 10
QUERY = COALESCE(NULL, 0)
```

Iria te retornar 10 + 0 = 10...
Se você quiser, pode trocar o `default` e por o valor que quiser.

Tente assim:

```
TOTAL + ISNULL(
 (SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValDeb,0))) - (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValCred,0))) FROM CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CSA 
   WHERE CSA.PlanoCtaCodRed          = @P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED 
     AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes >= @p_ANO_INI + '' + @p_MES_INI
     AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes <= @p_ANO_FIM + '' + @p_MES_FIM
     AND CSA.EmpCod like '%' 
         + (CASE WHEN @P_EMP_COD = '01' THEN '01.' 
            ELSE @P_EMP_COD END) + '%')
  ,0)
```

ou

```
TOTAL + COALESCE(
 (SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValDeb,0))) - (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValCred,0))) FROM CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CSA 
   WHERE CSA.PlanoCtaCodRed          = @P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED 
     AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes >= @p_ANO_INI + '' + @p_MES_INI
     AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes <= @p_ANO_FIM + '' + @p_MES_FIM
     AND CSA.EmpCod like '%' 
         + (CASE WHEN @P_EMP_COD = '01' THEN '01.' 
            ELSE @P_EMP_COD END) + '%')
  ,0)
```

**EDITADO**

Com todo o seu script agora deu pra entender um pouco melhor... Tente assim

```
DECLARE @TOTAL NUMERIC(18,2)

SET @TOTAL = (SELECT TOP 1 PTB.PATSLDCTAVALCONTAB 
                FROM PAT_SALDO_CONTA PTB  WITH (NOLOCK), CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CS WITH (NOLOCK)
               WHERE CS.PlanoCtaCodRed = PTB.PlanoCtaCodRed
                 AND PTB.PlanoCtaCodRed  = '18872'
                 AND PTB.PatSldCtaAnoMes = '201809' 
                 AND PTB.EmpCod like '%' + (CASE WHEN '01.13' = '01' THEN '01.' ELSE '01.13' END)+ '%')
            +(SELECT COALESCE(@TOTAL, 0)
                     + COALESCE((SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValDeb,0))) 
                                       -(SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValCred,0))) 
                                   FROM CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CSA 
                                  WHERE CSA.PlanoCtaCodRed = '18872' 
                                    AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes >= '2018' + '' + '10'
                                    AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes <= '2018' + '' + '10'
                                    AND CSA.EmpCod like '%' + (CASE WHEN '01.13' = '01' THEN '01.' ELSE '01.13' END) + '%')
                                ,0))

SELECT @TOTAL
```

Comment: será que ele vai retornar sempre vazio? tinha que retornar 10 + 0 = 10, e retornou 0

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca Se você executar apenas o select da query sozinho, qual o retorno?

Comment: NULL, pq não tem valor

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca Editei minha resposta, leia ela novamente, pois o `COALESCE` serve para isso mesmo, retornar um valor default caso sua query retorne `NULL`

Comment: Cara deu certo, se colocar 10 ele retorna os 10 msm, pq na query não possui nenhum valor, só que vou editar a pergunta pra vc ver que tenho uma query antes e ela retorna um valor tipo 9302.00 somando com a 2 query que é zero ela retorna null

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca Porque você criou a variável `@TOTAL` do tipo `VARCHAR(100)` se você quer usar ela como valor numérico? Verifique a edição da minha resposta!

Answer (score 0):

use a função COALESCE

seria assim:

```
COALESCE(TOTAL + (
 SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValDeb,0))) - 
  (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValCred,0))) FROM CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CSA 
    WHERE CSA.PlanoCtaCodRed = @P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED AND 
        CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes  >= @p_ANO_INI + '' + @p_MES_INI
        AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes <= @p_ANO_FIM + '' + @p_MES_FIM
    AND 
  CSA.EmpCod like '%' + (CASE WHEN @P_EMP_COD = '01' THEN '01.' ELSE 
  @P_EMP_COD END) + '%'
  )),0)
```

no seu caso use assim

```
TOTAL + COALESCE((
 SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValDeb,0))) - 
  (SUM(ISNULL(CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaValCred,0))) FROM CONTAB_SALDO_MOV_CTA CSA 
    WHERE CSA.PlanoCtaCodRed = @P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED AND 
        CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes  >= @p_ANO_INI + '' + @p_MES_INI
        AND CSA.ContabSaldoMovCtaAnoMes <= @p_ANO_FIM + '' + @p_MES_FIM
    AND 
  CSA.EmpCod like '%' + (CASE WHEN @P_EMP_COD = '01' THEN '01.' ELSE 
  @P_EMP_COD END) + '%'
  ), 0)
```

o que ela faz é retornar o valor setado depois da virgula caso o valor da query seja null ou false.

Comment: Cara eu fiz mas ele retornou 0, tinha que ter retornado 10

Comment: mude o ,0 para ,10 ^^